# How to display name instead of id in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "clients" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "address"   TEXT,
    "telephone" TEXT,
    "passport"  TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE "requests" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "date"  INTEGER,
    "client_id" INTEGER,
);
```

I have loaded them using SQLiteDataAdapter into DataTable objects.
With this code, I am displaying a table called "requests" in the DataGridView:

```
_requestsDataGridView.DataSource = requestsDataTable;
```

The column titled "client_id" displays the id for which the request was created. How can I connect the second DataTable to the DataGridView and make the name of the client who created the request appear instead of the client_id?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing this in the query. Using an INNER JOIN should give you the results you are looking for. Something like…

```
SELECT date, name From clients
INNER JOIN requests on requests.client_id = clients.id
```

This should return one table with two columns the client name and request date.